# How create digital signature for sharepoint document library?

Tags: sharepoint-2013, office365, digital-signature, electronic-signature

If anyone knowledge about how to implement/create a digital signature for SharePoint 2013 and online document library?

Any answer will be highly appreciated. This is new for me. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Infowise](https://www.infowisesolutions.com/product.aspx?id=SignatureField) is another option (I don't work for Infowise).  I use them in custom training forms - the trainee and trainer both sign that the training has been completed.

I didn't realise it before, but the above link shows that it can also be used to sign off documents.  (Though the OOTB Approval workflow can also be used for this purpose, of course).

Answer (score 0):

[I work for DocuSign]

The DocuSign for SharePoint product supports true digital signatures for SharePoint documents.